# Google Analytics query for sessions

Tags: r, google-analytics

I am trying to analyze visits to purchase in google analytics through r.

Here is the code

```
query.list<-Init(start.date = "2016-07-01",
             end.date = "2016-08-01",
             dimensions = c("ga:daysToTransaction","ga:sessionsToTransaction"),
             metrics = c("ga:transaction"),
             sort = c("ga:date"),
             table.id = "ga:104454195")
```

I have this code which shows error as 
`Error in ParseDataFeedJSON(GA.Data) : 
  code : 400 Reason : Sort key ga:date is not a dimension or metric in this query.`

Can you help me to get this desired output

Days to Transaction  Transaction  %total
0                      44         50%
1                       11        20%
2-5                     22       30%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to sort your results based on a dimension, which is not included in your result set. You have `ga:daysToTransaction` and `ga:sessionsToTransactions` dimensions, and you have tried to apply a sort based on `ga:date`.

You'll need to use this for sorting:

```
sort = c("ga:daysToTransaction")
```

It is not clear for me, if you'll use ga:sessionsToTransactions in an other part of your script, as it'll add an other breakdown compared to your desired output, which needs to be aggregated later to get your expected results.

Also, will you calculate %total in an other part of the script, or you expect it to be returned as part of Analytics response? (About which I'm not sure, if it's possible in GA API or not.)

Comment: Thanks,.. Your query matched 0 results. Please verify your query using the Query Feed Explorer and re-run it.
Error in GetDataFeed(query.uri) : 
  no loop for break/next, jumping to top level When I sorted based on sort = c("ga:daysToTransaction")

Comment: Might not be the root cause, but you have a typo in metrics, at least in your included code above: it should be `ga:transactions`.